# Any memory-efficient but "encapsulated, slice-friendly" way to pass a "linspace"-type array to functions in Python/numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am modifying software that plots and processes time series. The time/X values are evenly spaced, whereas the Y values are arbitrary. The way the architecture is currently designed, both time/X and Y values are generated upon initializing the program and explicitly stored in numpy arrays. Upon events being received by the software, these are passed to functions that follow the pattern do_something(x,y,params). These calls may be chained.

However, the downstream "do_something" functions often need only a fraction of the total length of the arrays. Since the entire array of Y values needs to be explicit anyway, the implementations of "do_something" incur no additional overhead with respect to Y by being passed a reference to this entire array and slicing it as needed. However, it would save a great deal of memory to only generate the X values within the slice, on the fly. The obvious way to do this, though, is to not pass a single parameter "X", but to pass a starting value that "aligns with" y[0], along with a step size as a separate parameter. Then whenever Y is sliced, the new starting X is calculated as old_start + step_size*low_index, and finally an X array is computed right as it's needed.

While very doable, this is kind of "ugly" because it breaks the symmetry of X and Y both being single reference arguments, to Y being a single reference argument and X being a pair of value arguments, and the downstream code all has to "remember" to handle these differently. It would be nice and "more Pythonic" to have some sort of object that by operator overloading does this automatically, i.e. it "holds" the start and interval "inside" it, and then an operation that "looks like" slicing outputs an array of just those values, that can be sent to matplotlib or whatever as an argument. The overhead of doing this would need to be fast though--because when scrolling through time the slice is constantly "moving".

Is there a natural way to create such a thing?

Comment: Probably not, especially if you're unhappy with a (initial value, step size) tuple describing your "linspace-type array". Post some code examples of what you think this thing might look like and how you actually envision using it.

Comment: The Python built-in range works nicely in this way `>>> range(1, 20)[3:7]
range(4, 8)` maybe try looking at its implementation to take inspiration

Comment: You can treat a `slice` object as the source for 3 values, e.g. `s=slice(2,8,2); np.arange(s.start,s.stop,s.step)`

Comment: `np.r_[s]` also does that `arange` operation with a slice. (and `linspace` with a complex step).  For more idea on how to implement custom "slicing" look at the `np.lib.index_tricks.py` file.

Comment: @Woodford Since these arrays are only being generated at one spot in the code, I just changed the overall program organization such that this piece of code "knows" what the limits are (as the analogous code for Y needs to "know" that anyway). Then it's just passed on. The biggest change this required was to change from a "push" to a "pull" semantics for the array generation--rather than consumers being pushed arrays once and updating the limits independently, they now have to ask for what they need each time they update. It was a decent barrier to get over but worth it in saved memory!